# Create JSON object with array array as attribute in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, json

I'm trying to create a JSON-String that looks like this:

```
{"id":"1","name":"new group test","beschreibung":"this is a description","gewerbe":"1" , "members":[{"uniqueid":"100110001"},{"uniqueid":"100110002"},{"uniqueid":"100110003"}]}
```

Right now my output looks like this:

```
{"data":{"id":"1","name":"new group test","beschreibung":"this is a ne","gewerbe":"1"},"members":[{"uniqueid":"100110001"},{"uniqueid":"100110002"},{"uniqueid":"100110003"}]}
```

Using the following PHP code:

```
return array('data' => $data, 'members' => $members);
```

$data is the result of a SQL-query and $members is a result array of another SQL-query. I want to have my members array as an attribute inside of data like in the example I posted. How do I create string like that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$data['members'] = $members;
return json_encode($data);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change structure of array:

Instead of

```
 json_encode(array('data' => $data, 'members' => $members));
```

use:

```
$data['members'] = $members;
json_encode($data);
```